# Winsock2.h Connecting to ip address without passing it on command line

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, winsock2

While I was checking basic use for `winsock2.h` library I asked myself how can i make program that connect automatically to IP address passed in source code without typing the address in command line all the time

Comment: Can I ask you why you want to avoid `getaddrinfo()` ?

Comment: @Albert Shown i just want to make things faster and i find it useless in my program and im curious how to do it

Comment: Local host or Remote?

Comment: @Albert Shown Remote

Comment: You could be looking for [inet_pton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-inet_pton)

Comment: I did it once, it was a local host, so instead of everytime parsing "localhost", I completely ignored `getaddrinfo()`, then I provided manually the necessary data (family, socktype, protocol) to `socket()`. It works but doesn't worth it, no improuvment in the speed as local host is already fast.

Comment: @user4581301 when i try to use connect function it tells me that i need pointer to sockaddr struct

Comment: Sooner or later you're gonna need a `sockaddr` to call `connect` or `send`. There are only so many shortcuts you can take.

Comment: @user4581301 you mean sockaddr_in?

Comment: @einpoklum than you you solved my issue and when i said i want to make things faster i just mean by that is passing the ip address all the time was time wasting and not for what i want to make

Comment: All of the socket stuff was written in C and C doesn't have formal inheritance, just a few aliasing tricks and a general agreement. For all intents and purposes,`sockaddr_in` [is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `sockaddr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AlbertShown says in his comment, you can manually provide the results of the `getaddrinfo()` function to whichever function needs them. You just need to have a look at the results it gives you when you do run it, and make sure and sure the appropriate protocol family, protocol and socket type. [Here's an example program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo) using these fields.

However - this is not a useful thing to do. You wrote in a comment that you want to "make things faster" - remember the maxim: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Is your program actually being slowed down by running `getaddrinfo()`? How much of the program's execution time does calling this function take? Use a profiler, or place a timer in your code, and figure this out. I'm sure you'll find it is a lot less than you think. It is almost certainly not worth bothering avoiding this function call.

Comment: yeah im sorry i didn't know that argv not getaddrinfo is getting address from command line

Comment: Do you know maybe why microsoft didn't show sockaddr_in structure usage in basic use in microsoft documentation? And is there any difference between addrinfo and sockaddr_in because they give the same result.

Comment: @fre: I have no idea why Microsoft does things...